# Excessive usage of lock in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have inherited some C#  code that I need to do fine-tuning. Since the dictionary (in the following code) is created on stack meaning individual instance (created by different threads) will be used for each call and it is not necessary to use the lock in this case, is that correct? Looks to me, it is not necessary.

```
private object textLock = new object();
private Dictionary<string, string> GetMyTexts(Language language)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> texts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DisplayText> pair in Repository.DisplayTextCollection.Texts)
    {
        string value = pair.Value.Get(language);
        //other code ....
        lock(textLock)
        {
            texts.Add(pair.Key, value);
        }
    }
    return texts;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Is the instance used by other threads? That's the only thing that's important, not how the instance is allocated. In this case, nobody else can modify the dictionary until it's returned and becomes Someone-Else's-Problem

Comment: Yes, the object and the method is called by other threads

Comment: I'd expect at most a concurrent access to `Repository.DisplayTextCollection.Texts` but protecting `texts` is really senseless here.

Comment: Just make sure that `//other code ....` doesn't assign `texts` to a field....

Answer (score 4):

For clarification, the dictionary is created on the heap - it's only the reference to the dictionary which lives on the stack.

Since no other thread or context has access to the reference until the method returns, no other code can simultaneously modify the dictionary, so the lock where it is currently is useless.

On the other hand, if the lock were outside the foreach loop, it might have been used to make sure only one of these methods is executing at any one time (for example, if `Language` or `Repository` was not thread safe)

Comment: more conditions: if "other code" is not going to start any threads and texts is not passed to those threads.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are correct and the `lock` is useless, but to remove any doubt that someone may have, let me ask you a question:

Isn't this part of

```
//other code ....
```

containing a call to a method or some code that can acquire both the `textLock` and the `texts`?

This would be the only case when some other thread could insert into `texts` while locking also the `textLock`. ***If that is not the case, then you can safely remove the `textLock`.***

Comment: `text` is a local, no other thread can access the object it refers to until the method returns. The lock is unnecessary.

Comment: @InBetween a local variable can be passed to several invocations of `Task.Run` for example, or passed to a method which does the same, or it could be stored in a field for another method to access.

Comment: Thanks, there is no usage of texts in those call only it contains checking about value string

Comment: @RotatingWheel then you got your answer! I've been working on big chunks of code that would have done error prone things like this one so always be careful when modifying legacy code.

Comment: @InBetween, there was a part of the code not shown in the question. I know it is more theoretical, but it would still be possible for it to exist in the actual method.

Comment: @canton7 duh, ok, sorry, misunderstood `//other code` as calling code. Sorry about the mess.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is just one thread supposed to be accessing that dictionary, according to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) that `lock` statement wouldn't be necessary.

> The lock statement acquires the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executes a statement block, and then releases the lock. While a lock is held, the thread that holds the lock can again acquire and release the lock. **Any other thread is blocked from acquiring the lock and waits until the lock is released**.